# How Instagram autolikers bypassing the API deprecation?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

In the past, Instagram autoliker, autofollower, like exchanger bots worked with the Instagram API. Thankfully, to keep Instagram - bot safe, they deprecated their API functionallity, so developers can no longer use Commenting, Liking endpoints.
But nowdays, I'm again meet new and new spam comments under a picture in the feed.
I did some research about the new autolikers.
How did the developers, like SocialCaptain bypass the API deprecation?
Are they simulating the user browsing instagram.com?

Comment: Yes, they're likely browsing the site programmatically using a library like Selenium or something similar. It'll be a little harder for them, but far from impossible. That almost certainly violates Instagram's TOS, but evidently that won't stop them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can just monitor the requests being sent from `instagram.com`. Open the developer tools and navigate to the *Network* tab.

Now you can reverse engineer their API by looking the requests they send on particular actions. The only thing left is to supply the proper `body`, `headers`, `cookies`, etc and perform the requests on your own outside of `instagram.com`.

Hope it helps !